# C structure self free

Tags: c

I am wondering if I can free a structure use the method defined in the structure. Here is a simple demo codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct testmem {
    int a;
    void (*free)(void *);
} testmem;

void xfree(void *mem) {
    testmem *tm = (testmem *)mem;
    printf("Before: a = %d\n", tm->a);
    free(mem);
    printf("After: a = %d\n", tm->a);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    testmem *tm = (testmem *)malloc(sizeof(testmem));
    tm->free = xfree;
    tm->a = 10;
    (*tm->free)(tm);
    return 0;
}
```

I use `gcc toy.c -o toy` to compile the code and it produces the following result

```
Before: a = 10
After: a = 0
```

I want to know whether I have successfully free the memory I allocate.
My confusion is that when `tm->free` is called to free `tm`, then `tm->free` will be also freed, will `tm->free` corrupt when it is be executed?

Comment: `tm->a` has undefined behavior. You can't access memory after calling `free` on it.

Comment: *"I am wondering if I can free a structure use the method defined in the structure."* **Yes.** *"I want to know whether I have successfully free the memory I allocate."* **Yes.** The only thing wrong with the code is the `printf` after the `free`.

Comment: @StoryTeller My confusion is that when tm is freed, then the tm->free is also freed, why could it  be called?

Comment: when you free memory, you only do that - free the memory - the functionality of the code you wrote will still persist.

Comment: @Angusme After you have freed it, C does not allow you to access it , doing that is undefined behavior, and one cannot draw any conclusion as to what happens. It could work, it could crash, or something else could happen.

Comment: Side note: `(*tm->free)(tm);` should be rewritten as `tm->free(tm)`. There's no need for the obfuscation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My confusion is that when `tm->free` is called to free `tm`, then `tm->free` will be also freed, will `tm->free` corrupt when it is be executed?

`tm->free` is not the whole function. It's merely a pointer to it. The code of the `xfree` function is entirely outside the memory region any `testmem` object occupies.

You must also note the sequence of events here. `tm->free` is evaluated to obtain the address of `xfree` *before* anything in the body of the function is executed. So the pointer to the function is valid when the call is made. And it only has to be valid up to that point. The pointer can become invalidated during the execution of the function, but it no longer matters, since its value is no longer needed.

---

As a side note, and for some extra type safety, you don't need to mess with `void*` and pointer conversions. This has the same functionality...

```
typedef struct testmem {
    int a;
    void (*free)(struct testmem *);
} testmem;

void xfree(testmem *mem) {
    printf("Before: a = %d\n", mem->a);
    free(mem);
    // Can't use mem anymore, it's invalid after free is called
}
```

... but keeps you from passing unrelated pointer types to the function.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is valid(as stated by the rest answers) except the line where you are dereferencing a pointer after invoking free on it:

```
printf("After: a = %d\n", tm->a);
```

My answer will focus on proposing a way for identifying memory leaks in your programs in the future.

I would recommend using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). It is a powerful framework, one of its features is memory management analysis for your program. Actually it can inform you about memory leaks in your program.

There are many options but in a simple form you could run:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes -v ./<your_exe_name>
```

Running the above command:

```
 HEAP SUMMARY:
   in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 528 bytes allocated

All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

So it becomes clear that the free operation is performed successfully and your program does not have any memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

As @StoryTeller pointed out you shouldn't be dereferencing a pointer after calling free on it. But yes, free(mem) will free the memory allocated to tm.

Answer (score 0):

The principle is certainly valid and is used when dealing with polymorphic objects (void* data members that can mean different things).